A good reference for the graded version of Nakayama's Lemma
I am looking for a reference for a graded version of Nakayama's Lemma. Specifically, if $A$ is a local graded-commutative ring with unique maximal ideal $I$, $f:M\to N$ is a morphism of finitely generated graded $A$-modules for which the map $M/IM\to N/IN$ is surjective, then $f$ is surjective. Where can I find a reference for this?
